# React-Native: Native base button bordered custom border width

Tags: react-native, native-base

I need to increase the border width of Native base default button. The default width is very thin , but there is no proper guide to customise the buttons in native base docs. Someone please guide me to adjust the bordered button width(thickness) in Native base ( react native ).

Comment: how about using `borderWidth` in style? like `style={{borderWidth:10}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`borderWidth` from theme variables file https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/variables/commonColor.js#L257, this is commonly used across various components.

You can also customize this in https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/theme/components/Button.js